# Google Play Game Service Mutli player Invitations not received

Tags: android, google-play-games, multiplayer, gkturnbasedmatch

I am currently working on a turn based multi player game and using Google Play Game Service for this. All set up has been made. Users can login properly and and select the players to compete with. After the selection when user presses Play button nothing special happens. onActivityResult shows that list of invitees has been prepared and match is created too on the defined criteria. I checked via logs. But on the invitee phone I never got any invitation. I checked on emulator (GenyMotion which serves Google Play Services compared to default emulator of Android SDk) and 2 different Android phones but unable to receive the invitation. I have setup as suggested here

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer

Below is my Code. Kindly anybody look into it and let me know where the problem is.

(P.S. I also came to know Invitations are sent via Google Cloud Messaging and I enabled this service for the game in Developer Console)

MultiPlayerInit.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;    
import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.*;
import com.google.android.gms.games.*;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Players.LoadPlayersResult;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Invitation;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Invitations;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Multiplayer;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.OnInvitationReceivedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Invitations.LoadInvitationsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RoomConfig;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.turnbased.TurnBasedMatchConfig;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.turnbased.TurnBasedMultiplayer.InitiateMatchResult;

public class MultiPlayerInit extends BaseGameActivity
implements OnClickListener {

    // For our intents
    final static int RC_SELECT_PLAYERS = 10000;
    final static int RC_LOOK_AT_MATCHES = 10001;
    final static int RC_INVITATION_INBOX = 10001;
    final static int REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS = 10002;
    String mIncomingInvitationId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.multiplayer_init);

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.btnInviteFriends).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.btnGetInvitations).setOnClickListener(this);  
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInFailed() {
        // Sign in has failed. So show the user the sign-in button.
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.btnInviteFriends).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.btnGetInvitations).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! your sign-in attempt failed. Please check your credentials...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.v("Sign-in Failed","Sorry! your sign-in attempt failed. Please check your credentials...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() {
        // show sign-out button, hide the sign-in button
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.btnInviteFriends).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.btnGetInvitations).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Games.Invitations.registerInvitationListener(getApiClient(), new OnInvitationReceivedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInvitationRemoved(String arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onInvitationReceived(Invitation invitation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mIncomingInvitationId = invitation.getInvitationId();   
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have received an invitation from: "+invitation.getInviter().getDisplayName()+" with ID: " +mIncomingInvitationId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are now logged in successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.v("Sign-in Succeeded","You are now logged in successfully...");
        // (your code here: update UI, enable functionality that depends on sign in, etc)
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) {
            // start the asynchronous sign in flow
            beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
        }
        else if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_out_button) {
            // sign out.
            signOut();

            // show sign-in button, hide the sign-out button
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.btnInviteFriends).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.btnGetInvitations).setVisibility(View.GONE);          
        }
        else if (view.getId() == R.id.btnInviteFriends) {

            Intent intent = Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.getSelectOpponentsIntent(getApiClient(), 1, 3);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SELECT_PLAYERS);
        }

        else if (view.getId() == R.id.btnGetInvitations) {

            Intent intent = 
                    Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.getInboxIntent(getApiClient());
                startActivityForResult(intent, RC_INVITATION_INBOX);            

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);

        if (request == RC_SELECT_PLAYERS) {
            if (response != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // user canceled
                return;
            }

            // get the invitee list
            final ArrayList<String> invitees =
                    data.getStringArrayListExtra(Games.EXTRA_PLAYER_IDS);

            // get auto-match criteria
            Bundle autoMatchCriteria = null;
            int minAutoMatchPlayers = data.getIntExtra(
                    Multiplayer.EXTRA_MIN_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);
            int maxAutoMatchPlayers
                    = data.getIntExtra(
                    Multiplayer.EXTRA_MAX_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);
            if (minAutoMatchPlayers > 0) {
                autoMatchCriteria
                        = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(
                        minAutoMatchPlayers, maxAutoMatchPlayers, 0);
            } else {
                autoMatchCriteria = null;
            }

            TurnBasedMatchConfig tbmc = TurnBasedMatchConfig.builder()
                    .addInvitedPlayers(invitees)
                    .setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria).build();

            Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer
                .createMatch(getApiClient(), tbmc)
                .setResultCallback(new MatchInitiatedCallback());

        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xetree.guesspicwithfriends"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="2.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
                    android:value="@string/app_id" />

        <activity android:name="com.xetree.guesspicwithfriends.HomeActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.xetree.guesspicwithfriends.MultiPlayerInit"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request does not go out until you call `takeTurn()`.

[TurnBasedTurnBasedMultiplayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer.html#takeTurn(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.List%3Ccom.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.ParticipantResult%3E))